# how to change nodejs debug params

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I encountered a warning when I debugged my nodejs application with vscode. The info is as follow:

`` 检测到 Node.js v8.0.0，因此使用检查器协议调试。
node --inspect=44269 --debug-brk app.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:44269/ea070045-ac73-4bd6-a784-743f1c661c62
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:12124) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead.
(node:12124) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead. ``

I know I should replace `node --inspect --debug-brk app.js` by `node --inspect-brk`. However, I don't how (or where) to do that.

Comment: did you read this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging ? Maybe there you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: I had read the article, but I cannot find the solution. However, I find something else in the [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24762). It seems like a bug according to the issues.